# Is Proverbs an accepted book

Tags: books, prophet-sulayman, prophet-dawud

Is the book of proverbs written by the prophet Sulaiman, son of dawud, accepted by Islam ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sulaiman is accepted as a prophet and revered in Islam, but the Qur'an doesn't mention any scriptures written by him. This doesn't mean that the Book of Proverbs isn't valid, but it does mean that Islamically-speaking we can't speak to it's veracity one way or the other.

Like any other unconfirmed pre-Islamic scripture, it should be treated with caution and tested for validity rather than accepted blindly, as there's no guarantee that it hasn't been corrupted over time. But there's nothing wrong with accepting good wisdom from it as long as it doesn't conflict with known-good Islamic teachings.